# Hide ascx markup based on condition

Tags: html, asp.net, ascx

I have some small markup in an ascx, for example this simple a href, like:

```
if (siteUrl) {
    <a href="<%= siteUrl %>"> <%= Message here %> </a> 
}
 // otherwise don't display Url and message
```

(that I want to hide if a variable in the code behind file is null.)
Obviously the code above is an attempt and needs adjusting to work in ascx.

What is a good way to do this? Is there a way for example to put the markup in some sort of placeholder in the ascx and make that visible on condition? Syntax tips appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar way you use the `<% %>`, just not add the `=`, and your code will be as:

```
<% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteUrl)) {%>
    <a href="<%= siteUrl %>"> <%= MessageMe %> </a> 
<% }%>
```

You can also read [Scott Guthrie block for that syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2)